py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1593.saveAsTable. : java.lang.StackOverflowError
I am reading a file that has about 725 columns as Data Frame (df) and I then do some light trnasformation and append couple of columns about four on the final Data Frame (df_final). I then write or save the df_final using 'SaveAsTable' I get the error below:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1593.saveAsTable.
: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$SetBuilderImpl.$plus$plus$eq(Set.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$SetBuilderImpl.$plus$plus$eq(Set.scala:329)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.to(TraversableLike.scala:786)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.to$(TraversableLike.scala:783)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.to(Traversable.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toSet(TraversableOnce.scala:360)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toSet$(TraversableOnce.scala:360)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toSet(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.containsChild$lzycompute(TreeNode.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.containsChild(TreeNode.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChild$2(TreeNode.scala:757)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$5(TreeNode.scala:798)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:798)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.clone(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone(AnalysisHelper.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone$(AnalysisHelper.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$clone$1(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:747)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:783)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.clone(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone(AnalysisHelper.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone$(AnalysisHelper.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$clone$1(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:747)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:783)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.clone(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone(AnalysisHelper.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone$(AnalysisHelper.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$clone$1(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:747)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:783)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.clone(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone(AnalysisHelper.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone$(AnalysisHelper.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$clone$1(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:747)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:783)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.clone(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone(AnalysisHelper.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone$(AnalysisHelper.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$clone$1(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:747)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:783)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.clone(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone(AnalysisHelper.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone$(AnalysisHelper.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$clone$1(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:747)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:783)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.clone(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone(AnalysisHelper.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone$(AnalysisHelper.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$clone$1(TreeNode.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.applyFunctionIfChanged$1(TreeNode.scala:747)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:783)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:781)

I have tried using checkpoint() or cache() to increase performance . I have tried to increase number of DPUs , still no success.
Even tried to increase JVM stack size I tried and no success.
I have tried using checkpoint() or cache() to increase performance . I have tried to increase number of DPUs, still no success.
Even tried to increase JVM stack size I tried and no success.
conf = (SparkConf().set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Xss8M"))
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf = conf)

I am using AWS Glue
